# How to print single field data from json array

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have run a query using laravel DB facade and it's return a json array object, but when i want to access single field value from json array it's show an error.

Here is my Query part.

```
$dsale=DB::table('directsales')
            ->join('clients','directsales.client_id','=','clients.id')
            ->join('products','directsales.product_id','=','products.id')
            ->select('clients.client_name','clients.addr','directsales.*','products.name')
            ->where('directsales.client_id','=',$client_id)
            ->whereBetween('directsales.issue_date',[$fromdate,$todate])
            ->distinct()
            ->get();

            return $dsale;
```

this is my result.

```
[{"client_name":"client one","addr":"jdkdhjfkhdkshfds","id":1,"transaction_code":"IN--00000001","client_id":1,"product_id":1,"product_code":"P0007","unitperctn":20,"unitprice":100,"ctn":4,"pcs":5,"total":4500,"deliverd_by":"nazim","issue_date":"2017-12-01","created_at":"2017-11-28 13:55:29","updated_at":"2017-11-28 13:55:33","name":"Dano Instant 2.5 Kg Packet 6"},{"client_name":"client one","addr":"jdkdhjfkhdkshfds","id":2,"transaction_code":"IN--00000002","client_id":1,"product_id":1,"product_code":"P0001","unitperctn":12,"unitprice":100,"ctn":1,"pcs":1,"total":2,"deliverd_by":"majed","issue_date":"2017-12-01","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Dano Instant 2.5 Kg Packet 6"},{"client_name":"client one","addr":"jdkdhjfkhdkshfds","id":3,"transaction_code":"IN--00000002","client_id":1,"product_id":4,"product_code":"P0004","unitperctn":12,"unitprice":90,"ctn":1,"pcs":3,"total":6,"deliverd_by":"majed","issue_date":"2017-12-01","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"All time bread"},{"client_name":"client one","addr":"jdkdhjfkhdkshfds","id":5,"transaction_code":"IN--00000004","client_id":1,"product_id":1,"product_code":"P0001","unitperctn":12,"unitprice":100,"ctn":1,"pcs":0,"total":1,"deliverd_by":"majed","issue_date":"2017-12-12","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"Dano Instant 2.5 Kg Packet 6"},{"client_name":"client one","addr":"jdkdhjfkhdkshfds","id":6,"transaction_code":"IN--00000005","client_id":1,"product_id":4,"product_code":"P0004","unitperctn":12,"unitprice":90,"ctn":3,"pcs":3,"total":3510,"deliverd_by":"add","issue_date":"2017-12-03","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"All time bread"},{"client_name":"client one","addr":"jdkdhjfkhdkshfds","id":10,"transaction_code":"IN--00000007","client_id":1,"product_id":4,"product_code":"P0004","unitperctn":12,"unitprice":90,"ctn":1,"pcs":6,"total":1620,"deliverd_by":"majed","issue_date":"2017-11-01","created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"All time bread"}]
```

When i print client_name **$dsale->['client_name'][0]**  this way it's show error.

Comment: Try: `$dsale[0]['client_name']` - https://3v4l.org/nCQuV

Comment: that is not json, that is a collection or array of stdClass objects ... only when you are trying to 'echo' them will you see json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in array.. you need to get the index first, then get the object..

ex: 
if the item is an object, do like this..

`$dsale[0]->client_name;`

or if the item is an array type, do like this..

`$dsale[0]['client_name']`

Comment: i'm try this. return $dsale[0]['client_name']; but now show FatalThrowableError
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array this exception.

Comment: have you try $dsale[0]->client_name;

Comment: Thanks,  $dsale[0]->client_name; this is works perfectly.